# How to get changes in parent git branch to child branch?

Tags: git

I have parent branch 'development' from which a child branch is cloned 'child_dev'.

Some commits have been done in 'development' after 'child_dev' was created, which is not reflected in the child branch.

I tried :

```
git checkout child_dev
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/development
```

This brought the new changes to the local child branch 'child_dev'. I made some changes to few other files and tried to push it using:

```
git push origin child_dev
```

but it showed error - (non-fast-forward)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sure.... rebasing _rewrites_ history. If you try to push that branch into the remote, git won't like it (to git, it's like the branch diverged)... but that's not a problem. Just force-push (assuming you know what you are doing and you are not busting other people's changes on that branch).

Comment: Worth mentioning: Git branches never have parent/child relationships. Git *commits* do, and for the situation you're talking about, the lack of *branch* parent/child relationships is not important. But for talking with other humans, and thinking about what you are doing, it's best to drop this parent/child idea with respect to *branch names* as it will just get you into trouble later.